# WCFTestClient will not connect to service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8733/SolutionName/Service....
...There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8733/SolutionName/Service'.
 The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

The weird thing is that I was able to connect via WCFTestClient earlier today, before making any changes to the `Service` and `IService` files.

I have a basic service (self hosted) for testing modifications that uses the following configuration:

```
  <service name="SolutionName.Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SolutionName.IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/SolutionName/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  ....
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

I have the `httpGetEnabled="True"` like it is supposed to, but it still will not connect. I have tried deleting everything out of the output directory but the issue persisted.

EDIT--

This is the `IService`. The new methods are marked with a `//NEW`

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    #region SupportItems
    [OperationContract]
    PipkinEvent[] GetPipkinEvents();

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinEventType[] GetPipkinEventTypes();

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinEventTypeGroup[] GetPipkinEventTypeGroups();

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinTaskCategory[] GetPipkinTaskCategories();

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinDepartment[] GetPipkinDepartment();  //NEW

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinOffice[] GetPipkinOffice();  //NEW

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinJobClassification[] GetPipkinJobClassification();  //NEW
    #endregion

    #region InformationItems
    [OperationContract]
    PipkinStaff[] GetPipkinStaff();

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinPFUser[] GetPipkinPFUsers();

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinTask[] GetPipkinTasks(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinStaffOffice[] GetPipkinStaffOffice();  //NEW

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPipkinStaffOfficeAsOf")]
    PipkinStaffOffice[] GetPipkinStaffOffice(DateTime enteredDate); //NEW

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinStaffDepartment[] GetPipkinStaffDepartment();  //NEW

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPipkinStaffDepartmentAsOf")]
    PipkinStaffDepartment[] GetPipkinStaffDepartment(DateTime enteredDate);  //NEW

    [OperationContract]
    PipkinStaffClassification[] GetPipkinStaffClassification();  //NEW

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPipkinStaffClassificationAsOf")]
    PipkinStaffClassification[] GetPipkinStaffClassification(DateTime enteredDate);  //NEW
    #endregion       
}
```

Comment: well, you said you were able to connect before making changes...what were these changes?

Comment: The only changes I made were to add new methods and data contacts.

Comment: can you post the service contract? `IService`? Thanks

Comment: @Leo The service contract has been added.

Comment: does it work if you remove your changes ?

Comment: and try to enable tracing to get more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: @demas The combination of your suggestions fixed it. By gradually adding the new methods back, I was able to find the offending method and the tracing informed me that I did not have a `[DataContract]` attribute on one of my classed >_<.